# GWT: get html with css from widget

Tags: html, css, gwt

I am developing an online payment and when a user makes a payment, the system should give a cheque including payment details at the end of payment process. I am using GWT and my cheque should be in pdf format. I am wondering whether there is a way to get html code from a widget with its style(css). I need this to make it pdf. i have tried:

```
gwtWidget.getElement().getString();
```

but it gives merely html code, without css. Is there a better way to get it with css?

Any sugessions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are the styles defines explicitly in GWT code or do you want to get the style from your stylesheet?

Comment: Thanks for the comment and effort. I want to build pdf from my html file generated be gwt. of course, my styles are in my stylesheets. I have tried copying styles into sample html file and it worked fine, but in my project i have xml, and i need to put all my styles into all of my xml layouts. i can manage todo that, but i think there should be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
gwtWidget.getElement().getInnerHTML()
```

that returns **All of the markup and content within a given element**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried getStyle, but it only gives a string [object CSS2Properties].

Comment: I have tried, getInnerHTML() also returns mere html, without any style. Thanks anyway.